# Minix grep search with specific extensions

Tags: grep, minix

For school I have to do an assignment in which I need to use the `grep` command within minix to search the source tree for files containing "int main(". With the source tree being stored in `/usr/src`, I have the following command:

```
 grep -rn --include=\*.c /usr/src/  "int main("
```

The problem is that I can't get the command to only search in `.c` files. 
So the question is: how do I search, using `grep`, for any files containing `"int main("` while only searching in `.c` files?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this following will work:

```
grep "int main(" $(find /usr/src|grep .c)
```

This will take all the files in /usr/src, and see which ones have the string ".c" in their filenames, and then look for some string withing each of those files.  The grep withing the $( will not look inside of those files, because it looks in searches for whatever string in stdin, which it receives through the pipe.

EDIT:

This might not work, depending on the level of power your computers have.  On my laptop it returns "zsh: argument list too long: grep".  But the principle should work.

EDIT EDIT:

If you want to search (for example) also in, say, .h files, you could use the following:

```
grep "int main(" $(find /usr/src|grep .c|grep .h)
```

Comment: Works fine on my virtual machine, thank you very much!